# XML load fails or delay on loading

Tags: php, xml, echo

I am reading an xml file and I am loading it in my php file as

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
```

where $url is an external link.

How can I echo if the url fails to load & if it is not responding at a specific time?